# Why did cross validation accuracy suddenly decrease? and then increase again?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, accuracy

I am training a classification model in Tensorflow. Here is a screenshot of the graphs I obtained after training.
[image: Accuracy vs Epoch Graph]
The blue one is the training accuracy, while the orange one is the cross validation accuracy.
*Why does the cross validation accuracy suddenly go down* around epoch 28? (down to 20%)
It might have gone down because it started overfitting?? But why does it come right back up in the next epoch?

I'm trying to understand what this behavior tells me about my model, or the data or the problem. The model is a custom CNN model with custom layers.
I've encountered this a few times with the same data and similar model in the last week.

Comment: How many examples are in your validation set?

Comment: @chicxulub Validation has 3100+ examples.